# Prepare 'text's in a textbox with checkboxes and submit button

Tags: checkbox, textbox, submit, html

Sorry for taking your time. First of all don't be angry and please don't reprehend me because of asking this question. Before i ask you i really tried to read watch too many training books and videos. Here is my problem and do not know where to start.
**items:** checkbox, submit button, textarea
**what i need to do on an internet page:** when submit button clicked; if checkbox is checked a text that represented with that checkbox will come to the textarea.
for example: [checkbox]i am 30 years old >>>> [submit]  = [(textbox) i am 30 years old] 
i can do this with asp.net. but do not want to use that method. 
can jquery do this? or do i have to use php? 
can you show me basic code?
thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jquery... Try this...

check whether checkbox is checked...

```
$('#checkbox_id').is(':checked'){
    var value = $('#checked_value_id').val();
}

<button id="button" onclick="post_value()">submit</button>

function post_value() {

    $('#button').live('click', function() {
        $('#textbox_id').val() = value;
});
}
```

This might help you...